# Writing PHP date inside a div tag

Tags: php, date, html, tags

I want to make a blog, but I want to start timestamp the comments, but I want to start writing in the date inside a

This is my code:

```
<div id="midMain">
    'Zup?
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
    ?>
</div>
```

it shows only the "'Zup?" part, what to do?

Comment: Is error reporting turned on?

Comment: worksfor me -> `'Zup? Monday 16th of April 2012 10:38:37 AM`

Comment: Have you saved the file as .PHP on your web server? (or the appropriate file ext)

Comment: yes, i have.. it's saved as .php

Comment: I am using easyPHP, my proffesor recommended this one

Comment: Do ANY PHP files work? What happens if you make a file called test.php and inside it put: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` -- do you see the PHP information page?

Comment: i tried now, and it didn't work.. so what can the problem be, the apache is up and working.

Comment: do you even have the PHP module running on your webserver?

Comment: yes, well i did make it work now, thanks alot folks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, and it is displayed:

`'Zup? Monday 16th of April 2012 11:18:02 AM`

The problem is not that code.

Comment: yes, I did make it work.

my problem was simple, I hade to write in the URL : localhost/blogg.test

missed that part.